# SQL Server 2005 DateTime math

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, datetime

I'm trying to get the amount of time spent on something. I have the DateTime for the start and end of the thing in two columns. I can do:

```
 cnext.CreatedDate - c.CreatedDate
```

which results in something like this:

```
 1900-01-01 00:00:19.190
```

which means they spent 19.19 seconds on the thing. That's great for each row but i would like to group by the specific thing and sum up the time spent on each thing:

```
SUM(cnext.CreatedDate - c.CreatedDate)
```

but I get a:

```
Operand data type datetime is invalid for sum operator.
```

How should i go about getting the total time is I can't sum up DateTime types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't SUM datetime values. This is like taking the square root of a string.

Try:

```
SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, c.CreatedDate, cnext.CreatedDate))
```

Or if you want greater precision:

```
SUM(DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, c.CreatedDate, cnext.CreatedDate))
```

Comment: +1. The fact the poster appears to be suggest he has no date portion?

Answer (score 0):

If the date potion is 1/1/1900, convert the dates to floats, subtract them, and convert the result back to datetime.